# C++ spawning threads depending on CPU cores available

Tags: c++

Below is Python code creating a process pool, allocating one process per file, up to a maximum number of CPUs.

I'd like to translate this to C++ (but we use threads, not processes).

However, from what I can see `std::async` doesn't allow capping the number of CPUs.

How does `std::async` know not to overload the system? There's no point spawning 20 threads on a 2 core CPU.

I'd really prefer to avoid writing my own thread pool for something which must be very common.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=max_cpus)

for file in file_list:
    pool.apply_async(my_func, args=(file,),)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: std::async doesn't know you would need a threadpool for that. However spawning as many threads as cpu's doesn't mean you will have all cpu's for yourself.
I'll post a demo threadpool in a moment.

Comment: `std::async` doesn't (necessarily) blindly create as many threads as tasks you queue up. In practice the standard library implementers will have a thread pool, but the size of that thread pool is obviously an implementation detail likely based on hardware specs and/or heuristics.

Comment: @CoryKramer I understood that this is true for Windows/MSVC (it uses a threadpool) but not necessarily for other systems/compilers, and that those will just use a new std::thread for each call

Comment: You can use [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) to find the number of CPUs.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/thread_pool.html

Answer (score 0):

Example of a threadpool in c++, you can also use say the one from boost
(which is probably better tested).

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <exception>
#include <mutex>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

namespace details
{
class task_itf
{
public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

template<typename retval_t>
class task final :
    public task_itf
{
public:
    template<typename lambda_t>
    explicit task(lambda_t&& lambda) :
        m_task(lambda)
    {
    }

    std::future<retval_t> get_future()
    {
        return m_task.get_future();
    }

    virtual void execute() override
    {
        m_task();
    }

private:
    std::packaged_task<retval_t()> m_task;
};

class stop_exception :
    public std::exception
{
};

}

class thread_pool
{
public:
    explicit thread_pool(const size_t size) :
        m_is_running{ true }
    {
        std::condition_variable signal_started;
        std::atomic<size_t> number_of_threads_started{ 0u };

        for (auto n = 0; n < size; ++n)
        {
            m_threads.push_back(std::move(std::thread([&]()
            {
                {
                    number_of_threads_started++;
                    signal_started.notify_all();
                }

                thread_loop();
            })));
        }

        // wait for all threads to have started.
        std::mutex mtx;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ mtx };
        signal_started.wait(lock, [&] { return number_of_threads_started == size; });
    }

    ~thread_pool()
    {
        m_is_running = false;
        m_wakeup.notify_all();

        for (auto& thread : m_threads)
        {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    template<typename lambda_t>
    auto async(lambda_t&& lambda) 
    {
        using retval_t = decltype(lambda());
        auto task = std::make_shared<details::task<retval_t>>(lambda);
        queue_task(task);
        return task->get_future();
    }

    template<typename lambda_t>
    auto sync(lambda_t&& lambda) 
    {
        auto ft = async(lambda);
        return ft.get();
    }

private:
    void queue_task(const std::shared_ptr<details::task_itf>& task_ptr)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_queue_mutex);
        m_queue.push(task_ptr);
        m_wakeup.notify_one();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<details::task_itf> get_next_task()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_queue_mutex);
        m_wakeup.wait(lock);

        if (!m_is_running)
        {
            throw details::stop_exception();
        }

        auto task = m_queue.front();
        m_queue.pop();

        return task;
    }

    void thread_loop()
    {
        try
        {
            while (auto task = get_next_task())
            {
                task->execute();
            }
        }
        catch (const details::stop_exception&)
        {
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
    std::mutex m_queue_mutex;
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<details::task_itf>> m_queue;

    std::condition_variable m_wakeup;
    bool m_is_running;
};

int main()
{
    thread_pool pool(4);
    auto ft1 = pool.async([] {return 1; });
    auto ft2 = pool.async([] {return 2; });
    auto ft3 = pool.async([] {return 3; });
    auto ft4 = pool.async([] {return 4; });

    // pool is will still be waiting

    //synchronize with results
    auto r1 = ft1.get();
    auto r2 = ft2.get();
    auto r3 = ft3.get();
    auto r4 = ft4.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` will tell you how many CPU threads to have active at one time or how many threads you should keep in the thread pool (whether boost or if you roll your own).

Here is what the approach might look like:

- call `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` to get number of cores
- init thread pool (existing impl or your own) with result
- wrap the required computation in a `std::packaged_task` and submit the tasks to the thread pool job queue